# Wordpress Database Values Wrong Format

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

i created a custom database for my wordpress installation. I am able to insert and get variables to/from it. My problem now is that the format of the variables is wrong.

```
// $pdflink is a url
$datum = date('d-m-y');

global $wpdb;   
$tablename=$wpdb->prefix.'offers';

$wpdb->insert($tablename, array(
'benutzer' => $current_user_id,
'datum' => $datum,
'offer' => $pdflink,
),array('%d','%s','%s'));
```

[The database looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOEeQ.jpg)

$datum is "203" instead of "02.03.16" and $pdflink is "0" instead of a url.

What is wrong with it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are the data types of those fields in your database table(s)?

Comment: Did you set the correct type on each column of your table .. Example: DateTime for $datum and TEXT or VarChar for pdfLink

Comment: Thank you very much! Thats exactly what was wrong. I now set the correct types for each of my columns and it works!